# Create custom log file magento 2.4.5

Tags: psr-logger

I want to create a custom log file in Magento 2.4.5 .

Before, I was using the following method:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/Custom_Token.log');
$this->logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$this->logger->addWriter($writer);
```

Guess its not working in 2.4.5 version. Please help.

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-add-custom-logs-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function log($message) //create function which will create log with date
    {
        $fileName = date('Y-m-d').'_yourlogName.log';
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/' .$fileName);
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        return $logger->info($message);        
    }


            $this->log("In function==>line number" . __LINE__ ); // add logs
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
```

Comment: I used it like this:  

$this->logger = new \Zend_Log();  

$this->logger->addWriter($writer);

Then:  $this->logger->info('Select Query'. $query1); 

Its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses this format From version 2.4.3.

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('text message');
$logger->info(print_r($myArray, true));
```